# Password effect for WP8 Toolkit PhoneTextBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, passwords, wpftoolkit

I want to add a password text box to my WP8 project.

The obvious way to go was PasswordBox; however, I want to include a placeholder, which doesn't appear possible.

So I used the PhoneTextBox feature in the WP8 Toolkit, which does allow a placeholder ("hint"). However, that feature doesn't appear to have a way of specifying the field as a password field.

All I want is the little round dots instead of the characters :)

Comment: One thing you can do is create a textblock overlay and on top/click hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I had done. Used a passwordBox for the password masking effect of small circular dots, and used a normal text box to show hint in a slight gray kin of color.

Xaml is here:

```
        <!--used a textbox to show watermark and the other is a password box-->
        <TextBox x:Name="PasswordWatermark" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Password, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <PasswordBox Name="PwdBox" LostFocus="PasswordBox_LostFocus" Opacity="0" GotFocus="PasswordBox_GotFocus" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="Segoe UI"  KeyDown="PwdBox_KeyDown" PasswordChanged="PwdBox_PasswordChanged"/>
```

Just make sure that you set the margins and widths and padding so that these two boxes exactly overlap each other.

Here is the Code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to be executed when focus is on the password box.
    /// Basic function is to show the watermark in the password box.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object</param>
    /// <param name="e">RoutedEventArgs</param>
    private void PasswordBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckPasswordWatermark();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Code checking the status of the password box and managing the watermark.
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckPasswordWatermark()
    {
        var passwordEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PwdBox.Password);
        PasswordWatermark.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 100 : 0;
        PwdBox.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 0 : 100;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to be executed when the password box loses focus.
    /// Basic fuction is to show the watermark in the password box.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object</param>
    /// <param name="e">RoutedEventArgs</param>
    private void PasswordBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordWatermark.Opacity = 0;
        PwdBox.Opacity = 100;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PwdBox.Password))
        {
            PwdBox.SelectAll();
        }
    }
```

This is how it worked for me.

Comment: Edited my snippet. Hope it helps. Do vote up or accept if it worked out for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to avoid the use of a text block above the password box, but it looks like that is they way I'd have to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open source implementation of a PasswordBox with a watermark: https://github.com/JoshClose/WindowsPhoneControls

Comment: do you know if this has been tested in Windows Phone 8? It was authored in late 2011.

Comment: I'm quite sure it should work since it doesn't seem to have anything that WP8 doesn't support. Just copy over the classes and see if it works. If it doesn't it shouldn't be hard to adapt it.